# Isupper / tolower doesn't work

Tags: c++

here's the problem, my program does not change uppercase letter to lowercase letter. I can not figure out why doesn't it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string str="hEhEhehe";
    for(int i=0;i<str.size();i++){
        if(isupper(str.at(i)))
            tolower(str.at(i));
    }
    cout << str;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look at the return value for `tolower`.

Comment: It doesn't mutate the character, it returns the lowercased char. Characters are immutable. It would necessarily have to return a new character.

Comment: Btw. You could notice it by fact, that you are passing that character by value, so it is not possible to change it in function if you dont pass it via pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the value back to the index of the string.

```
if(isupper(str.at(i)))
        str[i] = tolower(str.at(i));
```

Comment: Let's hope the upper character is ASCII, or at least non-negative.

Comment: @Deduplicator I like my emojis to be lowercase

Comment: @Miket25 Sure, sure, I was thinking of something less fun like `Ä`.